# How to modify a passed in value and return it from a java method

Tags: java, object, deep-copy

I am trying to modify the passedin object and return it:

```
private Sample modifyObj(Sample obj) {
  obj.setValue1("value1");
  obj.setValue2("value2");
  return obj;
}
```

This gives me an error saying "method modifies the parameter".
I tried to do this, by having a local copy in the method too:

```
    private Sample modifyObj(Sample obj) {
      Sample obj2 = obj;
      obj2.setValue1("value1");
      obj2.setValue2("value2");
      return obj2;
    }
```

But still the same error. Is there a better way?

Comment: Add a picture of your actual "Sample" class file.

Comment: is it possible to paste whole code of yours ?

Comment: Also, in what environment do you get this error? Some online tool, or a local IDE? This is not a standard error from any java compiler I know, probably some additional static analyzer. Wild guess: the analyzer might be confused athat you both modify AND return the parameter. This is not too unusual in general, but perhaps there is some special styleguide that something in your toolchain is trying to enforce?

Comment: You could try if making your method static and/or removing the return statement changes anything about this error message.

Comment: Note that returning the value is not necessary, as you return the same object you received as a parameter (in both of your cases), and the caller already has that.

Comment: yes, ignore the error code(it's a spot bug defined in our project).  basically, the error code is around modifying the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, when you pass an `object` to a `method`, its reference is passed and all the modifications done on top of that is automatically applied to the passed `object` in caller. So I guess there is no need to return it unless you want to make a clone.

```
private void modifyObj(Sample obj) {
  obj.setValue1("value1");
  obj.setValue2("value2");
}
```

and at caller

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
modifyObj(sample);
//here when you access sample, you will get modified values anyways
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your error, creating a Sample class:

```java
public class Sample {

    private String s1, s2;

    public void setValue1(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    public void setValue2(String s2) {
        this.s2 = s2;
    }
}
```

and testing with a method like yours

```java
public class proofSemantic {

    private Sample modifyObj(Sample obj) {
        obj.setValue1("value1");
        obj.setValue2("value2");
        return obj;
    }
    public void makeTest() {
        Sample obj=new Sample();
        modifyObj(obj);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        proofSemantic proof=new proofSemantic();
        proof.makeTest();
    }
}
```

It produces no errors. Could you be more specific? BTW, I don't know this strange error. What Java machine are you using? What IDE?